# Spring Boot with Kotlin: Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 17 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.8

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, visual-studio-code, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've created a new Spring Boot project with the "spring initializr". I use Spring Boot version 3.1.2 and Gradle - Kotlin. I also ticked Java version 17. When i open up the project in VS Code it provides me with an error: `Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 17 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.8. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option kotlin(INLINE_FROM_HIGHER_PLATFORM)`

My `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.2"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin{
    jvmToolchain(17)
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

My Java version:

```
java --version
openjdk 17.0.8 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+7-Ubuntu-122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+7-Ubuntu-122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My Gradle version:

```
./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-07-10 12:12:35 UTC
Revision:     a38ec64d3c4612da9083cc506a1ccb212afeecaa

Kotlin:       1.8.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.8 (Private Build 17.0.8+7-Ubuntu-122.04)
OS:           Linux 6.2.0-26-generic amd64
```

I've tried to set the correct Java version in my `build.gradle.kts` but nothing worked. I even tried to set the `jvmTarget` to `1.8`. When i try to run the project i get an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Comment: Update: I can run "./gradlew bootRun" and the application will run. So i guess it's a VS Code problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are some hints that this is a bug. Does this still happen when you use:

```kotlin
plugins {
  id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.0-M1"
  id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.2"
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0"
  kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.0"
}
```

I'm not really sure what actually is required, so you could try just the latest versions:

```kotlin
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.10"
  kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.10"
```